Как выделить кнопки по середине на всю ширину?

HTML
<body id="container" class="dark">
    <header id="start">
        <div id="title">
            <h1 class="text">Врата Штейна</h1>
            <p id="org_title">Steins Gate</p>
            <img id="main_img" src="assets/6627453519.jpg" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div id="turn">
            <button id="turn_on">Светлая тема</button>
            <button id="turn_off">Тёмная тема</button>
        </div>
        <div id="navigation">
            <div id="main_characters">
                <h2 class="characters">Главные герои</h2>
                <ul id="nav_list">
                    <li class="nav_li"><a href="#Rintaro_Okabe">Ринтаро Окабэ</a></li>
                    <li class="nav_li"><a href="#Kurisu_Makise">Курису Макисэ</a></li>
                    <li class="nav_li"><a href="#Itaru_Hasida">Итару Хасида</a></li>
                    <li class="nav_li"><a href="#Mayuri_Sina">Маюри Сина</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <main>
        <article id="Rintaro_Okabe">
            <h2 class="name">Ринтаро Окабэ</h2>
            <img class="description_img" src="assets/210c8eb139f3a3fe731b13689dba8f92f71b1d08r1-768-512v2_hq.jpg"
                alt="Rintaro_Okabe" />
            <p class="description">
                Восемнадцатилетний студент первого курса Токийского электротехнического
                университета, но уже ощущает себя не только гениальным, но и, как это
                принято у гениев, — сумасшедшим учёным. Доказывает это он рассказами о
                таинственной «организации», которая неусыпно следит за студентом.
                Основатель «Лаборатории гаджетов будущего». Любит поговорить по телефону
                сам с собой и посмеяться как настоящий безумец. Его не всегда устраивает
                собственное имя, и он зовёт себя Кёма Хооин (яп. 鳳凰院 凶真), что можно
                перевести как «Феникс жестокой реальности». А вот его подруга детства
                Маюри (позже к ней присоединяется Дару) называет гения «Окарин», просто
                соединив первые буквы его имени и фамилии. Практически не выходит из
                своей «Лаборатории гаджетов будущего», поэтому его легко издалека узнать
                по белому лабораторному халату.
            </p>
            <p class="description">Цитаты</p>
            <ul id="quotes">
                <li class="quote_li">“Это выбор Врат Штейна!” – Коронная фраза Окабе.</li>
                <li class="quote_li">“Я великий безумный учёный, Хооин Кёма!”</li>
                <li class="quote_li">“Гениальная извращенка” – Окабе говорит Курису.</li>
                <li class="quote_li">“Это интеллектуальный напиток для избранных” – Окабе о Dr. Pepper.</li>
                <li class="quote_li">“Эм… Hey mister, I am mad scientist. It’s soo COOOL! Sonuvabitch.” – Окабе торговцу
                    значками, на ломаном английском.</li>
            </ul>
        </article>
        <article id="Kurisu_Makise">
            <h2 class="name">Курису Макисэ</h2>
            <img class="description_img" src="assets/sganime4.png" alt="Kurisu Makise" />
            <p class="description">
                Член «Лаборатории гаджетов будущего» № 004. Возраст — 18 лет.
                Талантливая исследовательница неврологии в американском университете.
                Когда ей было 17 лет, её исследование было опубликовано во
                всемирно-известном журнале «Science» (в аниме название заменено на
                «Sciency»). Окабэ часто называет её ассистентом или придуманным им
                прозвищем — Кристина (саму Курису это очень раздражает). На первый
                взгляд — спокойная девушка, краснеет, если кто-то незнакомый
                приближается к ней слишком близко, но в душе — полная противоположность:
                однажды заставила Окарина стоять на коленях три часа подряд, при этом
                грозясь ударить его книгой. Всегда стоит на своём, не любит проигрывать
                и не любит, когда кто-то пытается управлять ею.
            </p>
            <p class="description">Цитаты</p>
            <ul id="quotes">
                <li class="quote_li">“Произошло что-то серьёзное, если ты зовёшь меня по имени” – Курису говорит Окабе.
                </li>
                <li class="quote_li">“Чувства людей – воспоминания, которые преодолели время.”</li>
                <li class="quote_li">“Время летит так быстро. Сейчас я согласна с Эйнштейном. Время течёт быстрее или
                    медленнее в зависимости от восприятия. Теория относительности такая романтичная. И такая грустная.”
                </li>
                <li class="quote_li">(После поцелуя Окабе) ”Есть научное объяснение этого! Яркие воспоминания, например,
                    первый поцелуй, сохраняются в гиппокампе, и их труднее забыть.”</li>
                <li class="quote_li">“Скажи правильно, Хооуин Трусы-Кёма!” – Курису говорит Окабе</li>
            </ul>
        </article>
        <article id="Itaru_Hasida">
            <h2 class="name">Итару Хасида</h2>
            <img class="description_img"
                src="assets/1988447_Portuguese(Brazil)_KeyArt-OfficialVideoImage_43e1e196-dab3-4e33-a1c1-028ec416d2c5.jpg"
                alt="Itaru Hasida" />
            <p class="description">
                Известный под прозвищем друзей Дару — девятнадцатилетний подросток,
                который учится на первом курсе Токийского электротехнического
                университета. Также является членом «Лаборатории гаджетов будущего»,
                занесённый в список под номером «003», где его «специализация» —
                хакерские взломы. Ведь, несмотря на юный возраст, Дару отлично
                разбирается и в программном, и в аппаратном обеспечениях компьютера. Но
                эти умения никак не помогают ему в личной жизни. Неуверенный в себе с
                излишним весом, Дару просто боится людей и общается только с помощью
                компьютера. Для моральной поддержки выбрал культуру отаку. Дару не
                социопат и не опасен для общества. Он самостоятельно выбирает
                нетрадиционный образ жизни вне активного взаимодействия с другими
                людьми. Он сам навешивает на себя ярлык отаку. Это юношеский протест и
                своеобразный вызов, за которым на самом деле кроется ранимое сердце. И
                если бы нашёлся неравнодушный человек, он бы смог расшевелить Дару,
                выведя его из берлоги в люди.
            </p>
            <p class="description">Цитаты</p>
            <ul id="quotes">
                <li class="quote_li">“Это не имеет никакого смысла!.. Умри! Черт возьми!”</li>
                <li class="quote_li">“Human is dead… Mismatch.”</li>
                <li class="quote_li">“Можешь сказать: 'Да кто будет есть твой банан, извращенец?'”- Дару говорит Курису.
                </li>
                <li class="quote_li">“Скажи: 'Твой банан мягкий'.” – Дару говорит Маюри.</li>
            </ul>
        </article>
        <article id="Mayuri_Sina">
            <h2 class="name">Маюри Сина</h2>
            <img class="description_img" src="assets/scale_1200.png" alt="Mayuri Sina"/>
            <p class="description">
                Девушка, в свои шестнадцать лет ставшая членом «Лаборатории гаджетов
                будущего» под номером «002», сразу за её главой. А всё потому, что она
                неизменная подруга детства Ринтаро, и за это имеет право называть его
                лично придуманным именем «Окарин». Себя же называет «Маюси». Немного
                легкомысленна, что может быть следствием её увлечения — косплея, для
                которого она любит придумывать и шить разнообразные костюмы. Кроме того,
                Ринтаро про себя шутливо удивляется: «Похоже, у неё действительно ветер
                в голове». Но, по его же словам, несмотря на всю её несерьёзность и
                глуповатость, Маюри способна, как никто другой, подбодрить и будет
                рядом, если тебе это нужно. Не сидит ни у кого на шее, самостоятельно
                подрабатывает в мэйд-кафе, где официантки наряжены в костюмы горничных.
            </p>
            <p class="description">Цитаты</p>
            <ul id="quotes">
                <li class="quote_li">“Мы должны устроить мир во всём мире. Например, дать каждому по плюшевому Упе…”
                    –Маюри придумывает желание для Ди-мейла.</li>
                <li class="quote_li">“Посмотри, у нас появилось столько новых друзей: Дару-кун, Крис-тян, Руко-тян,
                    Сузу-сан, Моека-сан, Фейрис-тян, Браун-сан, Наэ-тян. Весной ты выглядел таким одиноким… Но сейчас
                    всё в порядке. Тебе больше не нужна Маюри в качестве заложника.”</li>
                <li class="quote_li">“Посмотри, у нас появилось столько новых друзей: Дару-кун, Крис-тян, Руко-тян,
                    Сузу-сан, Моека-сан, Фейрис-тян, Браун-сан, Наэ-тян. Весной ты выглядел таким одиноким… Но сейчас
                    всё в порядке. Тебе больше не нужна Маюри в качестве заложника.”</li>
                <li class="quote_li">“Посмотри, у нас появилось столько новых друзей: Дару-кун, Крис-тян, Руко-тян,
                    Сузу-сан, Моека-сан, Фейрис-тян, Браун-сан, Наэ-тян. Весной ты выглядел таким одиноким… Но сейчас
                    всё в порядке. Тебе больше не нужна Маюри в качестве заложника.”</li>
            </ul>
        </article>
    </main>
    <footer id="last_container">
        <img id="last_img" src="assets/1572868653_DimCoordinatedBeagle-mobile.gif" alt="logo" />
        <a id="begin" href="#start">Начало</a>
    </footer>
</body>

CSS
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: black;
}

#start {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 200px;
    justify-content: center;
}

#main_img {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 900px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border: 4px solid chocolate;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

#title {
    text-align: center;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 70px;
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    color: chocolate;
}

#org_title {
    margin-top: 0;
    font-size: xx-large;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    color: chocolate;
}

#turn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    right: 100px;
}

#turn_on {
    color: #ffe4c4;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 600;
    background-color: #d2691e;
    padding: 20px 40px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 8px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

#turn_off {
    color: #151414;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 600;
    background-color: #d2691e;
    padding: 20px 40px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

#turn_on:hover {
    transition: all 100ms;
    outline: 3px solid dimgray;
}

#turn_off:hover {
    transition: all 100ms;
    outline: 3px solid dimgray;
}

#turn_on:focus-visible {
    transition: all 100ms;
    outline: 3px solid darkgrey;
}

#turn_off:focus-visible {
    transition: all 100ms;
    outline: 3px solid darkgrey;
}

#turn_on:active {
    transition: all 100ms;
    background-color: #d75d07;
    color: #ffffff;
}

#turn_off:active {
    transition: all 100ms;
    background-color: #d75d07;
    color: #000000;
}

#container {
    transition: 500ms;
}

.dark {
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #d2691e;
}

.light {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    
}

#navigation {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    color: black;
    background-color: chocolate;
    height: 400px;
    flex-basis: 300px;
    border: 6px double black;
    border-radius: 14px;
}


.characters {
    text-align: center;
}

#nav_list {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
    gap: 40px;
}

a {
    font-weight: 600;
    color: black;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

@media (min-width: 1420px) {
    #navigation {
        position: relative;
        top: 300px;
        right: 150px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 1420px) {
    #turn {
        position: relative;
        
    }
}

@media (max-width: 960px) {
    #start {
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
    }

    #navigation {
        flex-basis: 300px;
        width: 300px;
    }

    #main_img {
        transition: all 200ms;
        max-width: 600px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 634px) {
    body {
        position: absolute;
    }
}


.characters {
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;

}

main {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 250px;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#Rintaro_Okabe, #Itaru_Hasida {
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    align-self: center;
    width: 80%;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    line-height: 36px;
}

#Kurisu_Makise, #Mayuri_Sina {
    align-self: center;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    width: 80%;
    flex-direction: column;
    /* margin: auto; */
    align-items: center;
    line-height: 36px;
}

.name {
    color: chocolate;
    font-size: 35px;
}

.description {
    color: chocolate;
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 16px;
}

#quotes {
    color: chocolate;
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.quote_li {
    text-align: start;
    color: chocolate;
    font-style: italic;
}

.description_img {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 600px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 4px solid chocolate;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

footer {
    margin-top: 200px;
}

#last_img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#begin {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: xx-large;
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
    flex-basis: 100%;
    color: chocolate;
    margin: 100px 0px;
}

#begin:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}


Я так понял вам нужно поставить кнопку по центру в таком случае
#my_button {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}


Спасибо за помощь! Пытался до этого также делать, но не получалось. чему-то Сейчас сработало и всё выглядит более адаптивно!

Дело в том что я поставил height: 100vh; если бы я поставил height: 100px; то кнопки были бы по 100px и в центре итих 100px
